# Hardware button for Menu: modification

Tags: android, kernel

Wondering if anyone has any idea where the hardware buttons are programmed in the Android source. I'm working on 2.3.4 right now and I would like to be able to replace the "Settings" button shortcut that shows up when the left-most hardware key is pressed.  I've tried googling for a few hours now with no luck...  Any info as to where within source this can be modified would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: this probably is in the low level code that is written by the device manufacturer to interface their hardware with the OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you are looking for, but the menu that pops up on the device's home screen is created by the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method inside the Launcher activity of the Launcher2 application.

[Here is a link to the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3.4_r1/com/android/launcher2/Launcher.java#Launcher) for the version used in 2.3.4.  If you are developing a custom launcher application, this is the method that would get triggered when your activity is running and the MENU button is pressed.

Comment: thanks I'll take a closer look at this. the Launcher2 app is part of the kernel code so it very well could be what I'm looking for

Comment: Well, no, it's part of the platform code not the linux kernel.  If this doesn't end up answering your question perhaps some more specific details about what you are trying to accomplish would be useful to provide a more targeted answer.

Comment: Er, yea sorry I'm bad with terminology. But I made a simple change to the code to test that segment and it appears to be what I'm looking for after all. I just need to change the intent that gets created in that segment.